# Start Whatsapp chat using ADB

Tags: android, adb, whatsapp, genymotion

I'm trying to create  `Whatsapp` chat using adb.

I know how to  open  `Whatsapp` using adb:

```
adb shell am start -n com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.Main
```

But don't  know how to open chat with specific phone  number.

Comment: You probably can't do that through adb. Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

To send message from whatsapp simply open this url using `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+[CODE][NUMBER]&msg=MESSAGE"`

**Detailed steps**:

- `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+[CODE][NUMBER]&msg=MESSAGE"`
- `adb shell input keyevent 22`(switch to attachment button)
- `adb shell input keyevent 22`(switch to send button)
- `adb shell input keyevent 66`(press send button)

**Edit**:
This is a single line code to send message using whatsapp-
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+[CODE][NUMBER]" && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul && adb shell input text "[MESSAGE]" && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 22 && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 66`

---

**If you want to do this in python here is a better way using template matching**

```
def image_position(small_image, big_image):
    img_rgb = cv2.imread(big_image)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread(small_image, 0)
    height, width = template.shape[::]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
    _, _, top_left, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + width, top_left[1] + height)
    return (top_left[0]+bottom_right[0])//2, (top_left[1]+bottom_right[1])//2

def click(tap_x, tap_y):
    adb("adb shell input tap {} {}".format(tap_x, tap_y))

def adb(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, _) = proc.communicate()
    return out.decode('utf-8')

phone='+yyxxxxxxxxxx'
message='demo message here!'
path_of_image_of_whatsapp_button='/path/here/whatsapp_send.png'

# open whatsapp and phone number
adb(f'adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone}"')
# wait
adb('ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul')
# enter message
adb(f'adb shell input text "{message}"')
# take screenshot of page
adb(f"adb exec-out screencap -p > screenshot.png")
# get the position of the whatsapp send button using template matching
x,y = image_position(path_of_image_of_whatsapp_button, screenshot.png)
# click the button with the help of x and y
click(x,y)

print(f'Message sent to {number}')
```

`path_of_image_of_whatsapp_button` looks something like this:

[image: Whatsapp send button image]

Comment: This is probably the best answer for this case, however for more involved situations it might be difficult to find the keyevents to send, in such cases you can use [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI), a tool from [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to help you generate python scripts to do it.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Never used Culebra GUI. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb to simulate a user touching the screen.
In order to do so you need to use the command:

`adb shell input tap x y`